# confused about openid

Tags: asp.net, authentication, openid, asp.net-membership

Q:

The first time i use the **Open ID** was in my favorite site stackoverflow , i like it so much, from this time to now, i have a set of questions about it:

1. **What** are the advantages of the open id ?is it just a login facility(more usable than the usual process of entering user name and password)?(i think it will confuse users who are not know them)
2. **Is** the open id more secured or less secured or it doesn't related to the security issue at all?
3. **Why** not all web sites (i mean the popular) use it?Is the implementation is that difficult?
4. **When** to use open id in a web site?
5. **Is** it considered as an alternative to the login control or not?
6. please if i want to to use the open id in my web application? **What** is the start point?**What** are the steps to begin ? **Is** it a big issue or i can use it in my web application?

Comment: I guess you would have answers for most of your questions if you google first. Btw, have you checked http://openid.net/ ?? And, this site have some resources for C# users: http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: Why not use the [OpenID FAQ](http://openid.net/government/faq/)? Besides, what has this to do with C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1, 2 "Can't remember your passwords?
  Tired of filling out registration
  forms? OpenID is a safe, faster, and
  easier way to log in to web sites."
  OpenID.net
- 3 "Chances are you already have an OpenID but don't even know it!" OpenID.net
- 4 To log in.
- 5 Yes
- 6 OpenID.net. Read whats on the site. Yes you can.